# What does 'Unique Common Irreducible Component' mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Im working through some stuff on representations of $S_n$. I came across a certain result and I am not sure exactly what it means.

We have some representations $V, W$ of $S_n$ (they are defined precisely but I dont think that is needed) and we are able to prove that
$$\dim \text{Hom}_{S_n}(V, W) = 1 $$
then they say "Let $Z$ be the unique common irreducible component of $V$ and $W$". I am not sure exactly what this means. Are we able to extract some dimension 1 representation from $V$ and $W$ since their hom space has dimension 1?

Comment: If $\dim \hom_G(V,W)=1$ then $V$ and $W$ are equivalent irreps of $G$. Unless they are themselves 1D, they do not have any 1D subreps (or any nontrivial subreps at all). The only thing I can think of is that they're using $Z$ to refer to the isomorphism type of $V$ and $W$, but it's unclear why they'd use the word "component" for this. How do they use the letter $Z$ in the sequel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V_{\lambda}$ be the irreducible representations of $S_n$ (over $\mathbb{C}$ a priori, but in fact they're all defined over $\mathbb{Q}$) and write $V, W$ as a direct sum $V \cong \bigoplus_{\lambda} n_{\lambda} V_{\lambda}, W \cong \bigoplus_{\lambda} m_{\lambda} V_{\lambda}$ where the $n, m$ denote multiplicities. Schur's lemma gives

$$\dim \text{Hom}_{S_n}(V, W) = \sum_{\lambda} n_{\lambda} m_{\lambda}$$

(exercise), so this dimension is equal to $1$ iff $n_{\lambda} = m_{\lambda} = 1$ for a unique irreducible representation $V_{\lambda}$ (meaning $V$ and $W$ both have a component isomorphic to $V_{\lambda}$ with multiplicity $1$, which is therefore unique) and $n_{\lambda'} m_{\lambda'} = 0$ otherwise (meaning $V$ and $W$ do not have a component isomorphic to $V_{\lambda'}$ in common).

$Z$ refers to $V_{\lambda}$. In terms of the unique-up-to-scale nonzero intertwining operator $f : V \to W$, $f$ factors canonically as a composite $V \to Z \to W$, where $Z \cong \text{im}(f)$.